# Basic Python Numbers

Tags: python, floating-point

Why does `0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 - 0.3` evaluate to
`5.5511151231257827e-17` in Python?

Comment: Agreed Precision wil vary...
but here 5.5511151231257827e-17 is incorrect!!

Comment: While not wanting to take anything away from the answers below, 5.55e-17 is really a *small* quantity and would be regarded as zero in most practical situations.

Comment: In case you don't understand the notation, the number you see means 0.000000000000000055511151231257827. Very small.

Comment: 0.1 is **not** representable exactly in **any** precision of a IEEE-754 floating-point format. You could use 128-bit extended doubles and still have the same problem, only the exponent would be even smaller.

Comment: just for fun I tried it in Python, Lua, Perl and Ruby.  they all show the same result: 5.55111512312578e-17

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because that's how floating point numbers work. If you want precise numbers, use the [`decimal`](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) module. If you want to use floating point numbers, you have to remember to round them to a specific precision when you are displaying them.

```
>>> print '%.2f' % (0.1+0.1+0.1-0.3,)
0.00
```

Comment: Exactly ... and since the other numbers were only specified to 1 decimal place, you can't seriously expect to display 17 decimal places in the answer.

Comment: More precisely, that is how *binary* floating point numbers work. Numbers represented by the Decimal type in Python are decimal floating point numbers.

Comment: Yeah, I could be clearer. By "floating point numbers" I meant the `float` type in Python.

Answer (score 7):

This is a problem with floating point numbers in general. See [this section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems) on Wikipedia for a description. Roughly speaking - there are rounding errors. Notice that the number you gave us was very small - about 0.00000000000000005551115123 . Here is [a more technical paper](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) about the subject.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is here: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 3):

You might be interested in knowing that Python 3 has improved the situation by changing how `repr` works. It will now give you the shortest string representation that will be converted back to the original float:

```
Python 3.1.1+ (r311:74480, Oct 11 2009, 20:19:13) 
[GCC 4.3.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 0.1
'0.1'
```

Older versions behave like this:

```
Python 2.6.4 (r264:75706, Oct 28 2009, 22:19:17) 
[GCC 4.3.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 0.1
'0.10000000000000001'
```

It is only the output of `repr` (called implicitly when you enter a value in the interactive interpreter) that has changed. The underlying values are still IEEE-754 floating-point numbers, and they still have the usual limitations:

```
Python 3.1.1+ (r311:74480, Oct 11 2009, 20:19:13) 
[GCC 4.3.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 0.1
0.1
>>> 0.2
0.2
>>> 0.3
0.3
>>> 0.1 + 0.2
0.30000000000000004
>>> 0.1 + 0.2 - 0.3
5.551115123125783e-17
```

Answer (score 2):

Because of the way floating points numbers are represented in a computer. It's not just a Python thing.

Comment: [Quote]
class Flt
{
 public static void main(String args[])
 {
  float w,x,y,z,ans;
  w=0.1f;
  x=w;
  y=w;
  z=0.3f;
  ans=w+x+y-z;
  System.out.println(ans);
 }
}
[/Quote]

In java gives 0.0

Comment: Because `System.out.println` rounds the number, which is exactly what the Python code in my answer does.

Answer (score 0):

As an example, consider representing 1/3 as a scientific number in base 10. With only a finite number of digits (say, 10), you'll wind up with a rounding error. Say 1/3 ≈ 0.3333333333e0. Then 1/3+1/3+1/3 (after first converting to decimal expansions) is represented as 0.9999999999e0, but 1 is 1.0e0. Similarly, 1/7 ≈ 0.1428571429e0, and 1/7+1/7 would be 0.2857142858e0, but the representation for 2/7 would be 0.2857142857e0. In both cases, the sum is off by 1e-10.